# jQuery append()/appendTo()/html() cause to fire javascript inside DOM

Tags: jquery

I am working with some legacy software which generates HTML and I need to do some manipulation with this HTML. In order to do so I want to clone all body content to variable and work on it in order to not change anything in browser window. Like this:

```
var tmp = jQuery("body").contents();
```

Then I try to do some modifications with *tmp* variable:

```
tmp.wrap("<span></span>");
```

The problem is HTML has <style> and <script> tags in the <body> and it looks like JavaScript fires up when I try to append *tmp* somewhere, or do wrapping. I'd like to know if there is a way to do $.append, $.appendTo without firing javascript inside of it? (except, filtering actual HTML and removing all <script> tags)

Comment: I need to do some modifications to DOM and in the end find resulting height() and width() of it. But even simple $("body").contents().wrapAll("<div></div>") triggers execution of all JavaScript embeded into body. I want to avoid it.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set a variable once, like `trigger = true` and wrap all you current code in an if statement:

```
if (trigger) { your scripts...}
```

then, before wrapping/appending the markup, set trigger to false (just don't also append to `trigger = true` one)